# Error in Date Cell in CSV

Tags: excel, datetime, csv, export-to-csv

I have a date column with **YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS AM/PM** format in Excel file(xlsx).

But when I am trying to save it in CSV format then the values in date column converts to **MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM** .
But I want to keep the values in the same format.

Please help me to solve this and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Custom format as `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM` in Type text box and save as csv should work

Comment: I used single quotes i.e. **'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM'** instead of double quotes in Custom format and it worked fine.

Comment: Actually you don't need to use quote

Comment: If I don't use quote then the same problem occurs. It converts date column to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM format when saved as CSV.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Excel 2013.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67963/discussion-between-sreekanth-pulagam-and-ravi-mamain).

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem with CSVs. You can't provide any sort of formatting information about the column to excel, and so it takes liberties with dates. One way around it is to trick excel into processing the column as a string value, instead of a date value, by wrapping it in `=""`, so an example csv might look like this:

**Sample.csv**

```
Name,Date,Note
Foo,="2014/12/03 12:14:15 AM",Bla
Bar,="2012/11/13 3:14:15 PM",Bla Bla
```

Excel will preserve the date format because it will process it as a string value, so it will not modify it in any way.

Comment: I cant wrap the date value in "" because there are millions of records in the file and it will be very difficult to change each record. Isn't there any custom format for this. However I used **'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM'** (including single quotes) in Custom Format and it worked fine.

Comment: Ah, the issue I was referring to is actually excel taking values that it thinks are dates, but actually are not dates, and trying to convert them into a date. So your case is a bit different since it is in fact supposed to be a date. Then I agree that a Custom Date Format is the best solution to this problem